# Youtube Uploader call on node save

Tags: files

I've just setup Youtube Uploader module version 7.1-2.1.
Everything works fine when I add video to the node manually.

What I want is to put video into youtube_uploader field from my PHP code.
For some reason get an error.

The part of the code is:

```
 // Create a node for song:
$language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$song = new stdClass();
$song->type = 'song';
node_object_prepare($song);
$song->title = $node->title . ' (' . $performer->name . ')';
$song->language = $language;
$song->uid = $uid;
...
$song->field_video_youtube[$language][0] = (array)$videoFile;
$song->field_video_youtube_video_title[$language][0] = $node->title . ' (' . $performer->name . ')';
node_save($song);
```

Youtube uploader field - field_video_youtube
field_video_youtube_video_title is extra field added as I get errors from PostgreSQL.

Messages from Postgres:

```
    2016-01-09 20:14:29 MSK ERROR:  null value in column "field_video_youtube_video_title" violates not-null constraint
    2016-01-09 20:14:29 MSK DETAIL:  Failing row contains (node, song, 0, 92084, 92077, und, 0, 43192, null, null, 1).
    2016-01-09 20:14:29 MSK STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO field_data_field_video_youtube (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_video_youtube_fid, field_video_youtube_thumb_fid, field_video_youtube_video_title, field_video_youtube_display) VALUES ('node', '92084', '92077', 'song', '0', 'und', '43192', NULL, NULL, '1')
```

What's wrong with the code?

Thanks in advance for your help!